# Whose state (or wavefunction) changes (or collapses) upon observation: System's or Observer's?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, observers, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse

I was learning about Qubit measurement and the basics of Quantum computing. The instructor forced a lot on the following statement : *Assume an isolated system S. Let an observer O interact with the system S to measure some property, state of Observer O will change as opposed to the state of S i.e.
$|S\rangle (|O_1\rangle+|O_2\rangle) $*

Almost every other resource mentions the opposite, i.e. *upon observation, state of the system is changed* or *Wavefunction of the system is collapsed when observed*.
(At first, I thought they are equivalent just like different observers in moving frames as discussed in relativity. But I still wanted to confirm)

Q1: Are these statements equivalent or do they have different meanings (shouldn't the above equation be $ |O\rangle (|S_1\rangle+|S_2\rangle) $ )? And if they do have different meanings, why did the instructor use the former?

Later, the instructor attempted to connect the given statement with the Many-Worlds interpretation which raised another question in a different context.

Q2: If Many-worlds interpretation is true, why do we always observe only the outcomes with the highest probability? According to Many-worlds, there exists some universe where results with lower probability would have been observed. Why is it always some different universe and not ours? (Is it again because the probability of observing those results is very, very small and the number of parallel universes is infinite? Does this question has some physics-related answer at all?)

Any insights will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Observer" is a classical object.

Comment: So that means both the statements are *not* equal?

Comment: The two statements seem to me somewhat incomplete as formulated. The state of observer changes, and the state of system also changes. If the state of observer didn't change we would measure nothing. But observer is classical - it is not described by a wave function.

Comment: I'm sorry if that's so. He just said that and went on. Anyways, saying that change in the state of only one entity (observer or system) would be wrong? That does sound more logical. Thanks!

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Observer is *postulated* to be a classical object, which destroyes the superposition (causes "wave function collapse").   Trying to use a theory self-consistently to describe its postulate is circular logic. But yes, once we *believe* in QM, we say that observer is a macroscopic, thermodynamic, etc.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I think my previous comment answers your question. I also think that your comments are not relevant to the OP.

Comment: @Vadim The purpose of my comments was to request clarification about how your original comment is relevant to the OP, because the word "classical" can mean several different things. I wasn't trying to answer the OP's question. I'll move on. I deleted my earlier comments to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MWI we can also observe outcomes that are less probable. They just are not seen as much as the most probable outcome. I think your teacher has read much of Bohr, who says that measurements alter or knowledge of physical systems. Which means the state of the observer is changed after measurement. This is of course the case but the physical system on which a measurement is made has changed too after the measurement.

Comment: If I  understand correctly, what you are saying is that measurement is a process like : 
$$|O\rangle (|S_1\rangle + |S_2\rangle) \longrightarrow |O_1\rangle |S_1\rangle + |O_2\rangle |S_2\rangle$$

Comment: @SolubleFish There is only one state for the observer. Like you write it seems as there are two observer states.

Comment: After measurement, the measurement apparatus can be in two state depending on which outcome was observed, no ?

Comment: The measurement apparatus is not in a superposition of two states before the measurement. Only the system on which you make the measurement is in a superposition. If you think that the measurement is a superposition too then, then no measurements can ever result in a reduction of a superposition.

Comment: I wrote $|O\rangle$ for the observer state before measurement (apparatus ready to make the measurement), and $|O_1\rangle,|O_2\rangle$ for the two possible observer states after measurement. The first is not meant to be a superposition of the latter

Comment: The observer can indeed end up in one of the two states O1 or O2. before the measurement he is in a state O that is unrelated to O1 and O2. Well, he can *think* about the two states O1 and O2, but that's another matter.

Comment: Then the equation I wrote is correct ?

Comment: After the measurement, the observer is either in an O1 or an O2  state. He (or she) only sees S1 or S2. Before the measurement, he was in a state that sees S1 and S2 superimposed.  Your equation doesn't express this.

Comment: After measurement (under MWI), the universe is in a superposition, whose component cannot interact (the cat is dead and the owner sad / the cat is alive and the owner relieved)

Comment: @SolubleFish The owner only becomes glad (or sad) *after* he sees that the cat is alive (or dead).

Comment: @DescheleSchilder What would be the correct equation? I am curious because what SolubleFish wrote is similar to what the instructor wrote.

Comment: @Samarth I don't think that there is a connection between the state of the observer and the state of the system he measures. The state of the observer is independent of the state of the system. (maybe some particles inside the observer are entangled with that of the particles that make up the system, but the observer doesn't make a measurement on these). If you want a connection I would say that before the measurement the state is O(S1+S2), while after it is either O(S1) or O(S2), so not a superposition of these.

Comment: But the state of the observer also changes, right? (by any chance, can you suggest some good reference material? That'll be really helpful)

Comment: @Samarth Why should it?

Comment: Because the observer made an observation and his state should be altered as well?

Comment: @Samarth Only the system on which he made an observation changed. Afterward, the observer will be different too. He might be glad or sad. But at the moment he makes the observation, why should his state alter too, in sync with the changed state of the system? Why should his state change? Only if entanglement is involved (between particles inside the system and particles inside the observer) a part of the observer will change. **If** the entangled particles are in a superimposed state, which is highly unlikely as this superposition will be probably be destroyed by an interaction in his body.